# Is there any way to perform md5 hashing in oracle sql developer on every field of an column, and store the result hash in corresponding column(md5)

Tags: oracle, hash, oracle-sqldeveloper, md5, oracle12c

```
select standard_hash(‘text’,’MD5’) from dual.
```

The above script provides md5 hashing in oracle sql developer
But i want to do hashing on my table column and store the result in corresponding field.

I have also tried:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(MD5) 
SELECT standard_hash(TEXT,’MD5’) from TABLENAME
```

but it is giving error: `ORA-01400 cannot insert into null`

Comment: Have you tried `UPDATE TABLENAME SET MD5 = standard_hash(TEXT, 'MD5')`?  At the moment you are trying to create new rows in your table with a hash value and nothing else, whereas it seems to me you want to add MD5 hashes to existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `standard_hash` will give you an output which you perhaps can't store in the same column you had, because the length won't be the same. To avoid this, I recommend you use `raw` as data type for the column where you want to store the hash value.

MD5 processes an arbitrary-length message into a fixed-length output of 128 bits, typically represented as a sequence of 32 hexadecimal digits.

```
SQL> create table test_normal ( c1 varchar2(20) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_normal values ( 'AbdiRSDAloPdi8978' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select standard_hash(c1) from test_normal ;

STANDARD_HASH(C1)
----------------------------------------
BD6062214847DB31BB40A0185E3F89B0FB6980BF

SQL> alter table test_normal add ( c2 raw(256) );

Table altered.

SQL> update test_normal set c2=standard_hash(c1) ;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test_normal ;

C1
--------------------
C2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AbdiRSDAloPdi8978
BD6062214847DB31BB40A0185E3F89B0FB6980BF


SQL> select standard_hash(c1,'MD5') from test_normal ;

STANDARD_HASH(C1,'MD5')
--------------------------------
E404D2867EB21AD65827E2858A07CA65
```

Comment: I have other column “MD5” in which i will be storing all corresponding hash. Is there any way i can store the result in md5 column fields

Comment: what do you mean by "storing the result in md5" , there is no such data type. You can store the md5 hash value in a `raw` column without any issue as in my example

Comment: Md5 is column name, which i will be using for storing all the hashes

Comment: what is the data type of this column?

Comment: Varchar(32 byte),

Comment: I have also tried:

INSERT INTO TABLENAME(MD5) SELECT standard_hash(TEXT,’MD5’) from TABLENAME

but it is giving error: ORA-01400 cannot insert into null. TEXT is the column on which i want to perform MD5 hashing

Comment: as I said, if the original column has the same length as the destination column, it will not work.

Comment: The original coloumn ‘TEXT’ on which i am performing md5 hashing is of type TEXT VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)

Comment: run `alter table modify column md5 raw(256)`

Comment: the other error has nothing to do with the hash. Put in the Original question the structure of the orignal table and the destination table, for sure you have a field with a NOT NULL constraint and you are inserting null on it

Comment: Original table and destination table are same. There are 2 columns in table ‘text’ and “md5”, i want to perform md5 hashing on text column and store the result in md5 column

Comment: put the ddl of the table in the question